# Looking for a piece of free software that will split a wav file into multiple pieces at the silences

Tags: audio, wav

I'm ripping my old LPs to wav files and want something to break the big album sized wav file into a wav file per track.
I almost got up the inspiration to learn the wav file format and write my own but this has got to be something somebody has done a million times over already.
Linux better, but I'll take a windows solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't fancy reinventing the wheel, [MP3Split](http://www.thefreewindows.com/?p=2061) (free) will do the job.

*"Mp3Splt is a free utility that will help you split mp3 and ogg files by marking cut points or by detecting silence. If you want to split an album, you can select split points and filenames manually or you can get them automatically from CDDB (internet or a local file) or from .cue files."*

Answer (score 3):

How about something that works on both linux and windows?

[Splitting recordings into separate tracks with Audacity](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Splitting_recordings_into_separate_tracks)

> Audacity® is free, open source software for recording and editing sounds. It is available for Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux, and other operating systems.

Comment: audacity is an amazing program (although in the past it had a tendancy to make my machine reboot) but it's a fully featured audio editor. Last time I checked (and it was a while ago) it didn't detect silence and write out multiple files. I realize now of course I didn't put that part in my question. :-)

Comment: @Stu - It has a `Analyze menu -> Silence Finder` now that should do what you want.